# Material UI - Height of the multiline InputBase is set to full height based on no of rows property when toggling the width

Tags: material-ui

I am using the Material UI react library. I have an InputBase component with multiline prop.

When the wrapper div/element is shrunk to 0px width and expanded to full width again, the InputBase with multiline property is set to a max height even though there is no content inside it.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-zhukovsky-5dric?file=/index.html

Has anyone faced this issue? Any possible solutions?